# Why won't the if-statements return values of type boolean and object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, typeof

I'm curious as to why the else if statements in the filter method do not return anything:

```
var moveZeros = function (arr) {
  const nonZeros = arr.filter(value => {
    if (value !== 0) return value
    else if (typeof value === 'boolean') return value
    else if (typeof value === 'object') return value
  })

  const zeros = arr.toString().match(/0/g).map(Number)

  const newArr = nonZeros.concat(zeros) 

  return newArr
}
```

Additionally, I would also like to know why I get a similar effect when I try to filter out zeros from an array:

```
const zeros = arr.filter(value => {
  if (value === 0) return value
})
```

Here is a sample array to test the function:

```
[ 0, 1, null, 2, false, 1, 0 ]
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? `filter` expects a boolean, you don't need to return the value

Comment: The purpose of the function is to move all the zeros at the end of the array, while preserving the order of the other elements. It is just an exercise, but I want to know why the filter method behaves this way.

Comment: because `0` is `falsey`. So when you do `return 0` it is the same as `return false` which means it is not going to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return value in the `filter` method, return the boolean which should be true if the value should be selected, like so:

```js
var moveZeros = function (arr) {
// also when you use !== 0, you don't need to check the type as it compares type
  const nonZeros = arr.filter(value => value !== 0)
  const zeros = arr.filter(value => value === 0)

  const newArr = nonZeros.concat(zeros) 
  return newArr
}

console.log(moveZeros([ 0, 1, null, 2, false, 1, 0 ]));
```